# Number of n-digit binary sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Question (Past paper: Discrete Combinatorics)

a) How many n-digit binary sequences are there without any pair of consecutive digits being the same? (3)

b) How many n-digit binary sequences are there without any pair of consecutive digits being 01? (3)

c) How many n-digit binary sequences are there with exactly m ones? Explain your answer. (4)

**My attempt:**
a) 2 sequences (010101... and 101010...)
b) n+1 sequences (000... and n sequences in the form 1000...; 11000...;111000...)
c) C(n;m)
Choose the m positions for the m 1's. Then fill the rest of the positions with 0's.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks good to me.